# Index and save last N points from a list that meets conditions from dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, indexing

I have a DataFrame that contains gas concentrations and the corresponding valve number. This data was taken continuously where we switched the valves back and forth (valves=1 or 2) for a certain amount of time to get 10 cycles for each valve value (20 cycles total). A snippet of the data looks like this (I have 2,000+ points and each valve stayed on for about 90 seconds each cycle):

```
gas1          valveW   time
246.9438     2       1
247.5367     2       2
246.7167     2       3
246.6770     2       4
245.9197     1       5
245.9518     1       6
246.9207     1       7
246.1517     1       8
246.9015     1       9
246.3712     2       10
247.0826     2       11
...          ...     ...
```

My goal is to save the last N points of each valve's cycle. For example, the first cycle where valve=1, I want to index and save the last N points from the end before the valve switches to 2. I would then save the last N points and average them to find one value to represent that first cycle. Then I want to repeat this step for the second cycle when valve=1 again.

I am currently converting from Matlab to Python so here is the Matlab code that I am trying to translate:

```
% NOAA high
n2o_noaaHigh = [];
co2_noaaHigh = [];
co_noaaHigh = [];
h2o_noaaHigh = [];
ind_noaaHigh_end = zeros(1,length(t_c));

numPoints = 40;
for i = 1:length(valveW_c)-1
    if (valveW_c(i) == 1 && valveW_c(i+1) ~= 1)
        test = (i-numPoints):i;
        ind_noaaHigh_end(test) = 1;
        n2o_noaaHigh = [n2o_noaaHigh mean(n2o_c(test))];
        co2_noaaHigh = [co2_noaaHigh mean(co2_c(test))];
        co_noaaHigh = [co_noaaHigh mean(co_c(test))];
        h2o_noaaHigh = [h2o_noaaHigh mean(h2o_c(test))];
    end 
end
ind_noaaHigh_end  = logical(ind_noaaHigh_end);
```

This is what I have so far for Python:

```
# NOAA high
n2o_noaaHigh = [];
co2_noaaHigh = [];
co_noaaHigh = [];
h2o_noaaHigh = [];
t_c_High = []; # time

for i in range(len(valveW_c)):
    # NOAA HIGH
    if (valveW_c[i] == 1):
        t_c_High.append(t_c[i])
        n2o_noaaHigh.append(n2o_c[i])
        co2_noaaHigh.append(co2_c[i])
        co_noaaHigh.append(co_c[i])
        h2o_noaaHigh.append(h2o_c[i])
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
# First we create a column to show cycles:
df['cycle'] = (df.valveW.diff() != 0).cumsum()
print(df)

    gas1    valveW  time    cycle
0   246.9438    2   1   1
1   247.5367    2   2   1
2   246.7167    2   3   1
3   246.677     2   4   1
4   245.9197    1   5   2
5   245.9518    1   6   2
6   246.9207    1   7   2
7   246.1517    1   8   2
8   246.9015    1   9   2
9   246.3712    2   10  3
10  247.0826    2   11  3
```

Now you can use `groupby` method to get the average for the last n points of each cycle:

```
n = 3 #we assume this is n
df.groupby('cycle').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-n:, 0].mean())
```

Output:

```
cycle   0
1   246.9768
2   246.6579
3   246.7269
```

Comment: I think you might want to use `.iloc` instead of `loc`. I believe the current code returns the average of all rows (equivalent to `df.groupby('cycle').mean()`)

Answer (score 1):

Let's call your DataFrame `df`; then you could do:

```
results = {}

for k, v in df.groupby((df['valveW'].shift() != df['valveW']).cumsum()):
    
    results[k] = v
    print(f'[group {k}]')
    print(v)
```

`Shift()`, as it suggests, shifts the column of the valve cycle allows to detect changes in number sequences. Then, `cumsum()` helps to give a unique number to each of the group with the same number sequence. Then we can do a `groupby()` on this column (which was not possible before because groups were either of ones or twos!).

which gives e.g. for your code snippet (saved in `results`):

```
[group 1]
       gas1  valveW  time
0  246.9438       2     1
1  247.5367       2     2
2  246.7167       2     3
3  246.6770       2     4
[group 2]
       gas1  valveW  time
4  245.9197       1     5
5  245.9518       1     6
6  246.9207       1     7
7  246.1517       1     8
8  246.9015       1     9
[group 3]
       gas1   valveW  time
9   246.3712       2    10
10  247.0826       2    11
```

Then to get the mean for each cycle; you could e.g. do:

```
df.groupby((df['valveW'].shift() != df['valveW']).cumsum()).mean()
```

which gives (again for your code snippet):

```
    gas1  valveW  time
valveW                         
1       246.96855     2.0   2.5
2       246.36908     1.0   7.0
3       246.72690     2.0  10.5
```

where you wouldn't care much about the time mean but the gas1 one!

Then, based on `results` you could e.g. do:

```
n = 3
mean_n_last = []

for k, v in results.items():
    
    if len(v) < n:
        mean_n_last.append(np.nan)
    else:
        mean_n_last.append(np.nanmean(v.iloc[len(v) - n:, 0]))
```

which gives `[246.9768, 246.65796666666665, nan]` for `n = 3` !

Comment: This helps a lot! How can I average the last N elements of each cycle? Your answer averages the entire cycle.

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe is sorted by time you could get the last N records for each valve like this.

```
N=2
valve1 = df[df['valveW']==1].iloc[-N:,:]
valve2 = df[df['valveW']==2].iloc[-N:,:]
```

If it isn't currently sorted you could easily sort it like this.

```
df.sort_values(by=['time'])
```